# функция внутри функции

Tags: php, jquery

есть несколько функций, в каждую из них хочу заложить проверку на разрешение выполнения данной функции, но есть нюансы

```
$("#formsubmit").click(function {

var operacia = 100;
prov_prav(operacia);

alert("выполняемся дальше");
// выполнение дальнейшего кода
}
```

Сама функция проверки - аякс запрос

```
function prov_prav(operacia){
var operacia = operacia;
alert("Номер операции - "+operacia);
jQuery.ajax({  
    type: "POST",
    url: "prov_prav_polz.php",  
    dataType:"text",
    data:{"operacia":operacia},
    cache: false,  
    success:function(response){
        alert(response);
    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert(thrownError); 
        alert("Ошибка выполнения скрипта");
    }
    });
 }
```

код PHP просто сверка существующего id пользователя с набором его возможностей
допустим он пока пуст, просто проверим что приходит...

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);

$oper_dobavlenia = 0;
if($oper_dobavlenia == 1) { echo "Операция разрешена"; }
else { echo "Операция запрещена"; exit(); } 

}
?>
```

ПРОБЛЕМА!!!

При выполнении данной цепочки сообщения выводятся след порядком

1. Номер операции - 100
2. выполняемся дальше
3. **и только потом** переменная operacia из массива POST

Соответственно порядок выполнения нарушен, почему не понимаю. Хотя по моему разумению должно сначала 3 сообщение потом 2.
ну и если в обработчике я возвращаю false то функция все равно выполняется и только потом осуществляется выход.

Comment: вы в курсе, что в аббревиатуре ajax, первая буква обозначает _Асинхронный_? и что это обозначает применительно к коду?

Comment: я понимаю что Асинхронный - "фоновый" обмен данными браузера с веб-сервером. А так спасибо за внимание!!! Всегда приятно услышать от таких как Вы "гуру" фразу: "Парень, ты в курсе что ты начинающий ЛОХ"  вместо: "у тебя неправильно построен функционал проверки... вот почтиай тут... вот смотри как реализовано тут..."

Comment: вопрос решен! как я и предполагал реструктуризацией кода. Спасибо всем! с использованием AJAX (это так для "учителя")